# How do I verify the value of a property in an HTML tag with a test in Vitest?

Tags: vitest

I'm very new to Vitest and unfamiliar with other modern testing tools.

I am thinking about writing some tests to make sure that my Vue component is displaying the correct information and/or connecting to the right websites. For example, if I have an `<a>` tag and want to be sure the value of the `href` property hasn't changed in the template, could I have a test that compares the actual value of the `href` property to an expected value? By the same token,  if I have an `<img>` tag and want to make sure that the correct value is in the `src` property, could I write a test for that? I'd love to see an example of tests like that!

I'm not sure if these are appropriate tests so please tell me if they're not so I don't waste time trying to figure out how to do something pointless.

I haven't found anything in the API that lets me access properties of an HTML tag and I haven't seen this attempted in any video or tutorial I've found so I suspect that it isn't something Vitest can - or should - do.  Or maybe the technique is obvious to everyone but me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't access to the href property of the a element, but you can do it with html() property of his container, example :

```
test('href attribute', async () => {
   const container = wrapper.find('.container');
   expect(container.html()).toContain('href="https://stackoverflow.com"');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion! Unfortunately, when I tried it (after I added a link with an href pointing to StackOverflow to my Vue component), I got this message from Vitest: Error: Cannot call html on an empty DOMWrapper. Any idea what I need to do to make that error go away? Maybe I need to install something?

Comment: You need to replace the wrapper.find('.container') with the class name of the DOM element containing your <a href>

Comment: It also could be an id : wrapper.find('#idOfTheContainer')

Answer (score 0):

this is how I do it using vitest and @testing-library/react:

1. I add test id to all my elements that i want to run tests on like this: data-testid="button-name".
2. Render the component(s) I will test.
3. Get the specific component by the test-id.
4. getting the attribute ("href")
5. Then checking if the value is what I want it to be.

example below:

```
    render(<Menu />);
    const supportButton = screen.getByTestId("supportButton");
    const href = supportButton.getAttribute("href");
    expect(href).toBe("/support");
```